# Row count showing 0

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

Count showing 0 even after successful data insert

```
  MainData helper2 = new MainData(this); //Change the name to your Helper Class name
    SQLiteDatabase db2 = helper2.getWritableDatabase();
    int userData = 0;
    Cursor data2 = helper2.getUserData();
    while (data2.moveToNext()) {
        userData = data2.getInt(data2.getColumnIndex("MessagesSent"));
    }
    ContentValues contentValues2 = new ContentValues();
    contentValues2.put(KEY_ID, MessageRecieverId);
    contentValues2.put(KEY_NAME, MessageRecieverName);
    contentValues2.put(KEY_MESSAGES_SENT, userData+1);
    long returnVariable2 = db2.update(TABLE_USER_DATA, contentValues2, null, null);
    if (returnVariable2 == -1) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Nope", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //-1 means there was an error updating the values
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"uf", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Its showing uf which means its inserting but when i call count method it shows 0 rows... can someone help me out please

Count

```
    public int getProfilesCount() {
    String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_USER_DATA;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
    int count = cursor.getCount();
    cursor.close();
    return count;
}
```

Activity

```
int profile_counts = myDBHlpr.getProfilesCount();
    Log.d("BLAHHHHHHH", String.valueOf(profile_counts));
```

Comment: whats your "count" query?

Comment: check edit @pskink

Comment: and what is the value of `returnVariable2`? maybe 0? if so. your "ufffff" was too fast

Comment: Idk but its not -1 so its uplaoded right? @pskink

Comment: `returnVariable2` means number of updated rows, what is the value of `returnVariable2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this

```
db2.update()
```

you are not inserting rows in the table, but you are updating existing ones.  
You must use

```
db2.insert()
```

to insert a new row.  
`db2.update()` returns the number of rows updated.  
In your case **because there are no rows** in the table it returns `0`.  
So when you compare the result to `-1` it fails and you see the `uf` Toast.
If no rows where updated returns `0`. 
So do this:

```
long returnVariable2 = db2.insert(TABLE_USER_DATA, null, contentValues2);
```

`db2.insert()` returns `-1` if the procedure was unsuccessful.